# Using unique_ptr and vector

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

I have this code:

```
v8::Handle<v8::Value> StartMethod(const v8::Arguments &args) {
    v8::HandleScope scope; // node_isolate
    int length = args.Length();
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<char[]>> argv;
    for(int i=0;i<length;++i) {
        if(args[i]->IsString()) {
            v8::String::Utf8Value str(args[i]);
            const int strLen = ToCStringLen(str);
            if(strLen) {
                std::unique_ptr<char []> data(new char[strLen+1]);
                strcpy_s(data.get(), strLen+1, ToCString(str));
                argv.push_back(std::move(data));
            }
        }
    }
    return scope.Close(v8::Int32::New(MainMethod(argv.size(), &(argv[0]._Myptr))));
}
```

I am using `std::move` and it is working fine.
When i do not use std::move it gives me compiler errors because of unavailability of `assignment` function.

But Does it guarantees that when vector changes its location, may be because of some internal re sizing and move objects around, nothing bad would happen ?

Comment: Am I the only one that noticed the `&(argv[0]._Myptr)` in the last line of this? *Accessing* that pointer through this mechanism is bad enough, I don't even want to *guess* why you're passing the address of it to... something. You would be hard-pressed to find something *less* portable or standard.

Comment: @WhozCraig I actually wanted `char **` at that location. Can you suggest a better method there.

Comment: Yes. `char *tmp = data.get();`, and use `&tmp` I assume this is a `strtol`-type function, and if so, and it returns termination info in the resulting pointer-to-pointer (i.e. it modified the pointer) the behavior is beyond undefined. Even *accessing* that member is implementaiton-specific, Use a temp ptr anyway. What you're doing now with `&(argv[0]._Myptr)` is *dreadful*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I got your question right, but under the assumption that std::vector doesn't have any unexpected behaviour, yes, it is garantueed.
By executing `std::move()` you transfer the control over the underlaying pointer to the `std::unique_ptr` in the `std::vector`. From this point on it should behave like a `std::vector<char*>`

Comment: Would it still retain properties of unique_ptr like deleting after going out of scope ?

Comment: Yes (in the sense that your allocated data is deleted when the `vector argv` goes out of scope - and in the sense that an individual piece of data is deleted when its `unique_ptr` is erased from the vector).

Comment: of course, executing `std::move()` transfers the control of the underlaying object to the `std::unique_ptr<char*>` in the `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<char*>>`, what that means is, that it is like if the old `std::unique_ptr<char*>` had never existed.

Answer (score 2):

`vector<T>::push_back` gives the strong exception safety guarantee for move-only types [if and only if the move construtor of `T` does not throw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488490/vectorpush-back-insists-on-using-copy-constructor-though-a-move-constructor-is/18858875#18858875).

In your case `T` is a `unique_ptr` for array objects, whose move constructor is declared `noexcept` (§20.7.1.3), so you are indeed fine here: If the internal resizing of the vector throws a `bad_alloc`, the vector will remain unchanged and usable.